# Spring Security: Handling user direct access to authentication-failure-url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am wondering how do we handle authentication when user directly accesses the authentication-failure-url ?

```
<security:form-login login-page="/login" 
                         username-parameter="username"
                         password-parameter="password"
                         default-target-url="/member/"
                         authentication-failure-url="/invalidlogin" 
                         />
```

I have this in my `security-context.xml` and /invalidlogin is a Controller for handling authentication failure, so I am wondering how do I handle direct accessing ? basically 2 case scenarios

1. An authenticated user tries to access invalidlogin
2. An unauthenticated user tries to access invalidlogin

Should I just put logic into my Controller for handling that or should I block user for accessing it directly?

Comment: Define "handling that"?  What is happening, and what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: i mean how do we deal with user enters the /invalidlogin directly into the url bar when he/she is either authenticated or unauthenticated